# Read an excel file, for each row create a txt-file. The code I am using creates only a text file for the last row of the excel table

Tags: python, excel, file, xlrd

I am a total beginner, worked through the theory of python with the app sololearn, but never coded for my own use until now. I have also searched here and found some promising answers, but not exactly matching to my needs. So I am hoping to get some advices from you guys.

Here is , what I wish to do:
I have a table-file (excel) with Artist Name in the first column, Album Name in the second column and a web-link about this Album in the third column.
I would like python to create a txt-file for each row with the web-link from the third column. The correlated txt file should use Artist Name from first column and Album name from second column as the name of the newly created txt-file with a " - " in between Artist name and Album name.

Harald Nordgren was kind enough to write the following code for me:

```
import xlrd

def replace_with_underscores(cell):
return cell.value.replace(" ", "_")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("input-file.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in sh.get_rows():
    artist = replace_with_underscores(row[0])
    album = replace_with_underscores(row[1])
    link = row[2].value

filename = artist + "-" + album + ".txt"
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(link)
```

Applying this code to my excel table creates only one new txt-file with the value of the last row of the table.
I really hope someone could find the error in this code.

Thanks a lot to Harald Nordgren for writing the above code for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import xlrd

def replace_with_underscores(cell):
    return cell.value.replace(" ", "_")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("input-file.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in sh.get_rows():
    artist = replace_with_underscores(row[0])
    album = replace_with_underscores(row[1])
    link = row[2].value

    filename = artist + "-" + album + ".txt"
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(link)
```

Comment: Dear Harald, I have tried your code today on two other excel tables, but I always get only one txt-file created, namely only from the last row? Could you please help me and maybe point out where is my mistake?

Comment: Now I found my mistake! I didnt have a indent for the filename command. Now it is all work perfectly. Thank you very much, it was a great lesson for me.